# Use ngOptimizedImage for <picture> and .webp

Tags: angular

This picture component is used by a list component to present products with photos and text:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="dynamic.webp" type="image/webp" loading="lazy">
</picture>
```

While Angular v14.2 has [ngOptimizedImage](https://angular.io/api/common/NgOptimizedImage) to boost performance, seems it's only for `<img>`. How to use it with `<picture>` tag?